Encrypting ContactKeys to share with a vendor for use as a querystring GET parameter in a QR code
I've got a data extension with over 2500 records in it that I'm trying to modify as such: take the 'ContactKey' value, encrypt it using EncryptSymmetric() in AMPscript, and then assign the 'Encrypted ContactKey' value to the result. Here's my code:
SSJS:
<!--%%[-->

<div>

  <p id="secret" style="font-size: 40px; text-align: center;">

    Click to Edit SSJS

  </p>

</div>

<!--]%%-->

<!-- SSJS Header -->

<script runat="server">

  Platform.Load("core", "1");

  try {

  // SSJS Header

  // SSJS Core

  var moreData = true;

  var lbcClients = DataExtension.Init("LBC-Clients");

  var data = [1];

  while (moreData) {

      data = lbcClients.Rows.Retrieve({

          Property: "Unencrypted",

          SimpleOperator: "equals",

          Value: 1

      });

      if (data.length > 0) {

          // Process your data here

          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var contactKey = data[i].ContactKey;

            Write("ContactKey: " + contactKey + "<br>");

            Variable.SetValue('@ContactKey', contactKey);

            Platform.Function.TreatAsContent(Platform.Function.ContentBlockByID("1288227"));

            encryptedContactKey = Variable.GetValue("@EncryptedContactKey");

            Write("Encrypted ContactKey: " + encryptedContactKey + "<br><br>");

            // Update the "Unencrypted" field to 0

            lbcClients.Rows.Update({Unencrypted: 0}, ["ContactKey"], [contactKey]);

            lbcClients.Rows.Update({"Encrypted ContactKey": encryptedContactKey}, ["ContactKey"], [contactKey]);

          }

      } else {

          moreData = false;

      }

  }

  // SSJS Core

  // SSJS Footer

  } catch(error) {

    var formattedError = Stringify(error);

    formattedError = formattedError.replace(/\\r\\n/g, "<br><br>").replace(/\\n/g, "<br><br>").replace(/\\r/g, "<br><br>");

    Write(formattedError);

  }

</script>

<!-- SSJS Footer -->

AMPscript:
<!--%%[-->

<div id="secret" style="font-size: 40px; text-align: center;">

  Click to Edit AMPscript

</div>

<!--]%%-->

<!--

%%[

/* Initialize variables */

VAR @SymKey, @Salt, @IV /*, @ExecutionLog, @EncryptedContactKey */

/* Set encryption keys using External Keys from Key Management in Marketing Cloud Setup */

SET @SymKey = "xx"

SET @Salt="yy"

SET @IV = "zz"

/*

SET @ExecutionLog = CONCAT("AMPscript execution started...")

SET @ExecutionLog = CONCAT(@ExecutionLog, ",ContactKey: ", @ContactKey)

*/

SET @EncryptedContactKey = EncryptSymmetric(@ContactKey, 'aes', @SymKey, @null, @Salt, @null, @IV, @null)

/*

SET @ExecutionLog = CONCAT(@ExecutionLog, ",Encrypted ContactKey: ", @EncryptedContactKey)

SET @ExecutionLog = CONCAT(@ExecutionLog, ",AMPscript execution finished...")

*/

]%%

-->

I'm certain that the formatting at the top does not interfere, but I included it for transparency. There's also a lot of commenting and logging that's either toggled on or off, which I'm only fairly certain isn't interfering.
My main issue is in the batching of the necessary repeated calls of Rows.Retrieve() to iterate over all of the records in the data extension. When I run this on a CloudPage, it only ever performs the task on 2500 of the records, leaving out the rest. The CloudPage, however, times out and gives a "We couldn't open this page. Try again later." error.
Any help is appreciated.

are you sure you want to share your encryption parameters? :) I am editing them out

Oh, those are external keys in MC that relate to the /actual/ keys stored in Key Management, so I didn't think they merited obfuscating. But thank you!

First answer:
This looks like an XY problem https://sketchplanations.com/the-xy-problem
Why don't you just hash with SQL?
SELECT 
LOWER(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', CONVERT(varchar, Email)), 2)
) as hashedEmail 
FROM XYZ

and be done with it? This will run on any reasonable number of records and is one line of code.
The outside system cannot decrypt that.
It also cannot decrypt it your way, meaning it looks to me like it's an equivalent solution with NONE of your problems.
(edit: well technically they can, if they reverse engineer the encryption algorithm used in sfmc, as demonstrated elsewhere on this site; But point remains - I doubt you are encrypting it for them in a table so they decrypt it)
But you, inside SFMC, can decrypt it again by simple storing a mapping table of plain email / hashedEmail to resolve it coming back, and you can completely avoid encryptSymmetric etc. - all your code becomes unnecessary.
Second answer (this fixes symptoms of your chosen path; suggestion, do the above)
Analysis is simple.
The problem is the limit of max. 2500 records returned by
Rows.Retrieve({
          Property: "Unencrypted",
          SimpleOperator: "equals",
          Value: 1
      });

This limit exists to prevent timeouts of scripts that iterate forever.
Your script already runs long enough that a cloudpage does not like it.
Note that the cloudpage will give you that error sooner than a script activity, which allows 30 minutes. So running in an automation might help.
Can you circumvent the 2500 limit?
Limits exist for a reason. Hitting them means you are on a path not intended; they are best not interpreted as a prompt to get creative, but to reconsider. In other words, you are trying something that is "not intended to be done"(bulk encryption using the ampscript encryption function).
But YES, you can circumvent it. Then you risk timeouts again and might just another problem, depending on how many records you have.
With this disclaimer out of the way - at your own discretion :
You can switch to
var numberOfRows = 100000
var sorting = "_CustomObjectKey DESC"
var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows("nameOfYourDE"
,numberOfRows
,sorting
,'Unencrypted','1');

where you can specify a number larger than 2500.
take note that this works with the NAME of the DE, not the Customer Key of the DE, and You don't need to "init" the DE.
I will repeat: this might be just shifting the problem, is not intended use, is risking long execution time and timeouts, which you'd have to again circumvent by loop structures / time monitoring yada yada.

Love this. I think I'll go with your first solution, as you are absolutely right on the money that I'm getting creative to find a way around the limit. I sometimes lose sight of these simpler solutions if I zoom in on a complex solution, so I'm thankful for your answer.
I'd like to read the hashed email as a GET parameter when the prospect lands on the page; what's the simplest way? I'll chase down a solution in the interim, but we both know where coding alone got me last time...

Probably RequestParameter("whatever") (AMPScript) or Request.GetQueryStringParameter()(SSJS) assuming you mean a cloudpage? But that's another question entirely - and I am guessing the context - so I suggest opening a new question.
